# Sending JSON through JQuery to Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, cookies

I have a URL that accepts JSON through a post method. It should return a cookie and status.

When I try the following, (the username and password should be the JSON I'm trying to send) , I get no response, any ideas?

```
<script>
$.post("https://login-url",{"username":"user","password":"1234567890"},
function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   }, "JSON" );    
</script>
```

UPDATE:

After following DavidDorward's comment my code looks like this:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://loginurl',
    type: 'POST',
    data: '{"username":"user","password":"1234567890"}',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(msg){
     alert("Data Loaded win: " + msg);}
```

});

```
</script>
```

To describe my error a little better, a status should be returned, and a cookie. When I load this page firefox, and watch using firebug, there is no response, and no cookie information loaded in the header. Although it does seem to hit the URL, this makes me think its still a problem with the data. Although if the username and password are incorrect it should return an error, which is doesn't. It just consistently returns "null".

And to answer mattb's question, the login URL is only expecting "username" and "password" in JSON format and string datatype

Comment: what is the name of the request parameter that http://login-url expects the JSON data in? Or does it expect separate `username` and `password` parameters?

Comment: updated with more details matt!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery make a POST request with a JSON body, then you have to use the [ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) rather then one of the simpler alternatives. Specify the contentType as "application/json", convert your JavaScript object to a String containing JSON before assigning it to the `data` property.

Comment: Thanks David, I've updated my code, but I still seem to be having trouble - I've updated the post. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your data wont be sent as JSON this way.

'dataType: The type of data expected from the server.'
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Try:

`{"json": '{"username":"user","password":"1234567890"}'}`

Comment: I thought that was the problem, but when I tried what you said it didn't seem to change anything. Are you sure that makes the data json format?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have some sort of AJAX cross domain problem. For example, if the page you are running uses http and the url you are trying to access is using https, you will run into this problem.

The result is often what you describe: no response

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Regards,
Thomas Kahn

Comment: Hmm we're both https, but I'm https://www2 and they're https://app.sandbox. I assume thats enough to cause problems... Know of any possible solutions/workarounds?

Comment: When I was coding a solution that made requests to the Spotify (http://developer.spotify.com/) Metadata API, I built a webservice using ASP.NET that acted as a proxy. This allowed me to make AJAX requests within my own domain and still get the external data from the Spotify API. I'm not sure if this is the easiest way though.

Comment: You could take a look at JSONP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), but I'm not sure if will solve your problem in this case, assuming the problem is connected to the cross domain policy. Just to make sure, double check the jQuery AJAX syntax again. An AJAX post in jQuery will fail silently unless you have registered a handler to be called when the error occurs: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Answer (score 0):

Change the parameter dataType to 'json'. You don't necessarily need to include contentType

dataType : 'json'

Comment: I think that this settings will not work. `contentType` sets a format of sending data. Autor sends json, so he sets `contentType` to `json`. `dataType` sets a format for data sended by server. And there is no problem to convert any data to plain text. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)